# How to compute the energy of a time series?

Tags: time-series

I am analyzing the vertical component of 1Hz sampled geomagnetic data. These data were band-passed filtered around 0.01Hz (100s).

I would like to compute the daily energy contained in these time series. So far, I have tried computing the sum of the squared amplitudes of all samples:

[image]

Where zk are the samples of the vertical geomagnetic field time series.

**Is this the correct way of computing the daily energy contained in these band-passed filtered time series?** Should I take the square root of this sum, or normalize it by the number of samples in the time series?

Comment: You've got the right formula. Dividing it by the number of samples would make it energy per time, i.e. power. Keep it that way. (it's consistent to physics)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, Marcus! I am relieved that I am using the correct formula.

Comment: Looks like your formula it depends on the frequency of sampling. It is correct only by coincidence that your sampling frequency is 1Hs. What if your sampling frequency changes? In this case you should divide it by the number of samples per second.

Comment: Thanks for your message George. Yes, it is a coincidence that the sampling frequency is 1Hz.